# Ensuring that the serialization of an object is done correctly

Tags: java, serialization, applet, nullpointerexception

Is there a way to ensure that the serialization of an object is done correctly?
I created an applet that I serialize with `writeObject()` method and I have no Exception no error.
But when I try to de-serialize it with `readObject()` I got a NullPointerException.
My applet is kinda complex but I ensured that all my fields are serializable.

The class of the objection have nested classes.

Any guess as to what could have happen?

the code below is in my servlet it creates a SerialTree .

```
` SerialTree st = new SerialTree() ;

     try{
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/cof/test8"));

 out.writeUnshared(st);
 out.flush();
 out.close();
```

}

Here's the stacktrace :

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3575)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1865)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:536)
    at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1865)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:536)
    at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1865)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:536)
    at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1865)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:536)
    at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1865)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:536)
    at java.awt.Container.readObject(Container.java:3560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1865)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
    at arbre.ArbreClient.getHttpObject(ArbreClient.java:92)
    at arbre.ArbreClient.init(ArbreClient.java:123)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)`

here the lines 70 to 106 to the applet itself ,it tries to retrieve a serilaTree object ?

`
try{
    result = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/cof/test8"));

```
}
 catch(NotSerializableException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 catch(InvalidClassException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(StreamCorruptedException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(NotActiveException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(OptionalDataException  e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }

Object obj =null;

    try{

obj = result.readObject(); 

    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
    // System.out.println("lalal");
 }
 catch(NotSerializableException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(InvalidClassException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(StreamCorruptedException e){

     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: How about posting your stacktrace ?

Comment: You should check if all your fields are initialized when you set them. That's the most common cause for a NullPointerException.

Comment: I dont think so . I've tried with an object "car" where the brand is set to null and it works perfectly . about the stack trace : I get a NullPointerException on readObject() method .

Comment: Show the stack trace - it should show where exactly the null pointer occurs. (add it to the question.) If this does not yet help you, also add the relevant part of your source, and indicate the line numbers given there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, it doesn't make sense to ser/deser the type Applet. Try using a different class.

**Update:**
I have read your stacktrace, and what I see is that you tried to deserialize an applet while running an applet. I strongly suspect this to be the reason of your problem. Try moving all your variables into a different class (call it `MySerializableApplet` for example, and don't make it extend the class `Applet`), then operate your serialisation/deserialization on this one only.

Comment: it make sense when you have ressources only on the server so all you can do is to create this object in server-side and send it to you client-side to create your applet.

Comment: I was thinking that the browser is responsible for instancing the Applets. From where do you deserialize the applet? In a browser? And from which class?

Comment: I am not testing on a browser ,I am on my IDE (Eclispe).The NullPointerException occurs when I try to deserialize my object .

Comment: Seems that I have a NullPointerException during serialization and it is not reported  (very weird) I'll delve into it .